# time data 'Month' does not match format '%Y-%b' (match)

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Hi I am working on a data set given below

```
Month,Travellers('000)
Jan-91,1724
Feb-91,1638
Mar-91,1987
Apr-91,1825
May-91,
Jun-91,1879
```

I am using the below code to format the date

```
data = pd.read_csv('Metrail+dataset.csv', header = None)
data.columns = ['Month','Travellers']
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Month'], format='%m-%Y')
data = data.set_index('Month')
data.head(12)
```

However, getting the below error

```
ValueError: time data 'Month' does not match format '%m-%Y' (match)
```

Could someone help me what is the mistake and any useful links to learn more on the date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `%Y` is for **year on 4 digits** **< VS >**  `%y` is for **year on 2 digits**
2. `%m` is for **month with digits** **< VS >**  `%b` is for **shorten month name**

Also remove `header=None` because this counts the header row as data, this is wrong

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data.columns = ['Month', 'Travellers']
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Month'], format='%b-%y')
```

Comment: Still getting the error "ValueError: time data 'Month' does not match format '%m-%y' (match)"

Comment: `data = pd.read_csv('Metrail+dataset.csv', header = None)
data.columns = ['Month','Travellers']
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Month'], format='%m-%y')
data = data.set_index('Month')`
data.head(12)

Comment: @Newlearner You had 2 other errors, look agian at my code

Answer (score 1):

use `%b` and (as mentioned) `%y`

```py
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Month'], format='%b-%y')
```

From the [docs](https://strftime.org/)

> %b    Month as locale’s abbreviated name. Sep

Comment: getting this error ValueError: time data 'Month' does not match format '%b-%y' (match)